# Matrix Differentiation using Kronecker operator issue

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, kronecker-product

Let X an $n\times n$ variable matrix and given vectors and matrices $p_1$ ($1\times n$), $p_2$ ($n\times 1$), $\Omega$ ($n\times n$). What is the derivative of the function $f(X)=p_{1}X^{-1}\Omega Xp_2$ ?

I used the following three matrix differentiation rules found [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf):

$\frac{d(AXB)}{dX}=B^T\otimes A$, $\frac{dX^{-1}}{dX}=-(X^{-T}\otimes X^{-1})$ and the multiplication rule $D[f(x)^Tg(x)]=g(x)^Tf'(x)+f(x)^Tg'(x)$.

I broke $f$ down to a product of two functions: $g_1(X)=p_1X^{-1}\Omega$ and $g_2(X)=Xp_2$. Then I found the derivatives of each to be $\frac{dg_1{X}}{dX}=-(\Omega^T\otimes p_1)(X^{-T}\otimes X^{-1})$ and $\frac{dg_2(X)}{dX}=p_2^T\otimes I_n$, where $\otimes$, the Kronecker multiplication. However when I use the multiplicative rule the second component $$\Omega^TX^{-T}p_1^T(p_2^T\otimes I_n)$$ seems to have dimension that don't work out, unless we DO NOT take the transpose of $g_1$. I know the result should be a $1\times n^2$ matrix. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensionally, since $f$ is a scalar and $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, the derivative $\frac {\partial f} {\partial X}$ will be an $n\times n$ matrix.

The simplest way to get there is to use differentials.  First let $P = p_1^T p_2^T$, then you can write the function as
$$f = P:X^{-1}\Omega\,X$$
where $A:B$ denotes the Frobenius (inner) product between matrices $A,B$.

Now take the differential and rearrange it until you isolate $dX$ on the RHS.
$$ \eqalign {
df &= P:d\,(X^{-1}\Omega\,X) \cr
   &= P:(X^{-1}\Omega\,dX) + P:(dX^{-1}\Omega\,X) \cr
   &= (\Omega^TX^{-T}P):dX + (PX^T\Omega^T):dX^{-1} \cr
   &= (\Omega^TX^{-T}P):dX + (PX^T\Omega^T):(-X^{-1} dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
   &= (\Omega^TX^{-T}P):dX - (X^{-T}PX^T\Omega^T X^{-T}):dX \cr
   &= \big(\Omega^TX^{-T}P - X^{-T}PX^T\Omega^T X^{-T}\big):dX \cr
} $$
Passing from the differential to the derivative
$$ \eqalign {
\frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= \big(\Omega^TX^{-T}P - X^{-T}PX^T\Omega^T X^{-T}\big) \cr
} $$

**Update**

The problem with your initial approach is that your definition of $g_1$ is *already* transposed.

So $f \ne g_1^T g_2$ but instead $f = g_1 g_2$.

Now all the dimensions work out as expected.

Comment: OK, in that case the derivative should be a $1\times n^2$ matrix and not an $n\times n$ matrix right? I think for any mapping $g: \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ the derivative of $g$ with respect to the matrix $m\times n$ would give a matrix of dimensions $p*q\times m*n$.